# How to read and write data from yaml file at Run time in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

I wanted to read and write some content from `yaml` file in `Spring Boot` application. Which parser I have to use and How? If someone knows any idea, then please elaborate with an example.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml)

Check the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-loading-yaml) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SnakeYaml

1. Add dep e.g snakeyaml
2. The Yaml class is the entry point for the API:

   `Yaml yaml = new Yaml();`
3. Now we’ll parse a YAML document with the Yaml class:

   ```
   Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
   InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                                 .getClassLoader()
                                 .getResourceAsStream("customer.yaml");
   Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);          
   System.out.println(obj);
   ```